# how to plug height and time into a quadratic equation $h=at^2+bt+c$

Tags: mathematical-physics

How to plug height and time into a quadratic equation $$h=at^2+bt+c$$ to model the height of the object $t$ seconds after it is shot into the air?
The height is $163.6$ feet the time is $1.2$ seconds.

Is it like this:

$$h=163.6(1.2)^2+163.3(1.2)+0$$

Answer (score 1):

In your equation, $h$ is probably the height, $a$ is twice the acceleration ($-2g$), $b$ is the initial velocity, and $c$ is the initial height. The typical equation used for this is called a kinematic equation

$x = x_0 + v_0 t + \frac{1}{2}a_0t^2$,

where $a_0 = g = 9.8m/s^2$.

On the other hand, if you are just given this equation with no knowledge of the physical situation, you will have to plug in 163.6 for $h$ and 1.2 for $t$ and solve for $a$, $b$, and $c$. Also, you probably know that at $t=0$, $h=0$, so you can use this to find $c = 0$. However, you can't find $a$ or $b$ without more information about the trajectory (the velocity and acceleration at $t=0$, for instance).

Edit:

"After 1.2 seconds the object is 163.6 feet off the ground, at 4 seconds it is 307.8 feet off the ground, and at 5 seconds it is 298.5 feet off the ground"

Now you have three equations:

$163.6 = a(1.2)^2+b(1.2)+c$

$307.8 = a(4)^2+b(4)+c$

$298.5 = a(5)^2+b(5)+c$

By solving this system of equations, you can find the values of a, b, and c

Comment: This is what was given to me: An object sitting on a platform is shot into the air, and you are able to record its heights at various times: after 1.2 seconds the object is 163.6 feet off the ground, at 4 seconds it is 307.8 feet off the ground, and at 5 seconds it is 298.5 feet off the ground

Comment: Okay, so now you have 3 unknowns and 3 equations, so you can solve for a, b, and c by plugging in your values for each point and then solving the system of equations.

Comment: How would solve this system of equations to get a,b,c do I substitute a variable for

Comment: @student I have edited my answer to show the equations you need to solve. There are many ways to solve a system of equations, but one way is by substitution. Solve one equation for and substitute it into the other two equations. Then you will have those two in terms of b and c, so you can solve one for b and substitute it into the last equation to get c. Then, plugging c into the equations you've found, you should be able to get a and b.

Answer (score 0):

It looks you are actually being asked to find the values of the parameters $a$, $b$ and $c$. You know that:

- at $t=1.2$, $h=163.6$
- at $t=0$, $h=0$ (this is presuming the height is measured relative to where the object was shot from)

You can use the second piece of information to work out $c$. However you have not given enough information to find $a$ and $b$. (You need one more data point to determine $a$ and $b$ uniquely.)